# Subdivision modifier not working properly on a cylindric shape

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I applied a Subdivision modifier to my mesh and this is what I got

[image: before]

[image: after]

Actually, I expected this to become an ellipsoid

Comment: Hello, maybe try a M > Merge by Distance or check if you don't have inner faces?

Comment: @moonboots yes, you are right. I really had redundant geometry. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have overlapping vertices, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*